# AngularJS - how to redirect to detail properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I would like to ask how to redirect properly on detail page (or any app page)?

App is reading user detail data from REST api,

**so if i tried action in this order:**

- Click on detail button
- Route to given page and in data-ng-init is triggered Controller method
- Get ID from GET param
- Make request to REST API
- Display response in detail

I get few times detail page without data (I must wait for API response).

**I think, that better solution is this:**

- Click on detail button
- Trigger detail method on controller and receive data from REST API
- If are data valid, create scope with data
- Redirect to detail with all filled fields

Second solution is not working for me.

I tried to do by this way:

```
// fill scope by user data
$scope.UserDetail = data.result;
// redirect to user detail
var url = "users/detail/"+userId;
$location.path(url);
scope.$apply();
```

But data are not passed to the view (are not displayed).

**Question is:**

How to make redirect with data loading correctly and what are bets practices for this?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the `resolve` mechanism of `$routeProvider`. With that, you can wait for some promises (your API rest call) to be resolved before displaying your page..

Example :

```
yourModule.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/users/detail/:userId", {
            templateUrl: 'userDetails.tpl.html',
            controller: ['$scope', 'myRestData',
                function($scope, myRestData) {
                    // controller stuff
                    // myRestData contains the resolved promise
                }
            ],
            resolve : {
                myRestData : ['myRestService', function(myRestService) {
                    return myRestService.get(); //must return a promise
                }]
            }
        })

])
```

Now you just need a standard link to navigate to this url (or a manual `$location.path(url);` update)

More information : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider